# AWS OpsWorks - An error occurred while stopping the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, opsworks

Last few days my script (aws-cli) is unable to stop OpsWorks instance. I didn't change anything. When I log into aws.amazon.com it shows:

```
Status: stop_failed
Message: An error occurred while stopping the instance MyInstanceName
Internal Error
```

How to find out the root cause of the Internal Error? OpsWorks logs shows no errors or warnings.

If I try to stop it using web interface it stops after about 10 minutes.

Update 1: I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I didn't find any errors in Ubuntu log files.

Comment: Are you able to shutdown/terminate the instance manually in the EC2 console? A hard shutdown might be the only way to deal with this, if Opsworks is refusing to make the instance go away. If you have auto-healing turned on, you might want to turn it off if you don't want Opsworks to resurrect the instance once you've killed it by force.

Answer (score 0):

You should log into the instance and check the Chef logs located at **C:\ProgramData\OpsWorksAgent\var\commands\{*number*}.**

You might be able to find a clue as to what is failing. I would also suggest looking at the instance's Windows Event Log for any errors, specifically in the System and Application logs.

See the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-debug-log.html#troubleshoot-debug-log-instance) for more information about chef and agent logs.

Report back here with your findings.

Comment: OpsWorks logs without any errors as I wrote in the question. Also, I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I didn't find any errors in Ubuntu log files. Currently that VM is terminated, but I will take a second look, when this happens again.